# Why my Gateway returns with 403 status code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, ocelot

I have a service called Catalog. When I make a request as follows to access this service normally and take courses through the service, the request is answered successfully.

localhost:5011/api/courses

When I make the following request to receive all courses through the gateway, it returns with a 403 status code. For this I make a request as follows:

http://localhost:5000/services/catalog/courses

As a result, the same request is not responded to via the gateway.

Program.cs File of my Gateway project:

```
using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer("GatewayAuthenticationScheme",options =>
{
    options.Authority = builder.Configuration["IdentityServerUrl"];
    options.Audience = "resource_gateway";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
});

builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile($"configuration.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName.ToString().ToLower()}.json");

builder.Services.AddOcelot();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseAuthorization();
await app.UseOcelot();

app.Run();
```

Gateway is waiting for resource_gateway audience.

This audience is included in the token I sent.

The Config.cs file for the Identity server is as follows:

```
using System;
using IdentityServer4.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using IdentityServer4;

namespace FreeCourse.IdentityServer
{
    public static class Config
    {
        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources =>
            new ApiResource[]
            {
                new ApiResource("resource_catalog") { Scopes = { "catalog_fullpermission" } },
                new ApiResource("resource_photo_stock") { Scopes = { "photo_stock_fullpermission" } },
                new ApiResource("resource_basket") { Scopes = { "basket_fullpermission" } },
                new ApiResource("resource_discount") { Scopes = { "discount_fullpermission" } },
                new ApiResource("resource_order") { Scopes = { "order_fullpermission" } },
                new ApiResource("resource_payment") { Scopes = { "payment_fullpermission" } },
                new ApiResource("resource_gateway") { Scopes = { "gateway_fullpermission" } },
                new ApiResource(IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName)
            };

        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
            new IdentityResource[]
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Email(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
                new IdentityResource()
                    { Name = "roles", DisplayName = "Roles", Description = "User roles", UserClaims = new[] { "role" } }
            };

        public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
            new ApiScope[]
            {
                new ApiScope("catalog_fullpermission", "full access permission for Catalog API "),
                new ApiScope("photo_stock_fullpermission", "full access permission for PhotoStock API "),
                new ApiScope("basket_fullpermission", "full access permission for Basket API "),
                new ApiScope("discount_fullpermission", "full access permission for Discount API "),
                new ApiScope("order_fullpermission", "full access permission for Order API "),
                new ApiScope("payment_fullpermission", "full access permission for Payment API"),
                new ApiScope("gateway_fullpermission", "full access permission for Gateway API"),
                new ApiScope(IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName)
            };

        public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
            new Client[]
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientName = "Asp.Net Core MVC",
                    ClientId = "WebMvcClient",
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                    AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        "catalog_fullpermission", "photo_stock_fullpermission", "gateway_fullpermission",
                        IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName
                    }
                },

                new Client
                {
                    ClientName = "Asp.Net Core MVC",
                    ClientId = "WebMvcClientForUser",
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                    AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        "gateway_fullpermission",
                        "basket_fullpermission",
                        "discount_fullpermission",
                        "order_fullpermission",
                        "payment_fullpermission",
                        "catalog_fullpermission",
                        "photo_stock_fullpermission",
                        "gateway_fullpermission",
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes
                            .OfflineAccess,
                        IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName,
                        "roles"
                    },
                    AccessTokenLifetime = 1 * 60 * 60, 
                    RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,
                    AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime =
                        (int)(DateTime.Now.AddDays(60) - DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds, // 60 gun
                    RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse, 
                }
            };
    }
}
```

Ocelot configuration file:

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5011
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/services/catalog/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
        "Get",
        "Post",
        "Put",
        "Delete"
      ],
      "UpstreamScheme": "http",
        "AuthenticationOptions": {
            "AuthenticationProviderKey": "GatewayAuthenticationScheme",
            "AllowedScopes": ["catalog_fullpermission"]
        }
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5012
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/services/photostock/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
        "Get",
        "Post",
        "Put",
        "Delete"
      ],
      "UpstreamScheme": "http",
        "AuthenticationOptions": {
            "AuthenticationProviderKey": "GatewayAuthenticationScheme",
            "AllowedScopes": ["photostock_fullpermission"]
        }
    }, 
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5013
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/services/basket/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
        "Get",
        "Post",
        "Put",
        "Delete"
      ],
      "UpstreamScheme": "http",
        "AuthenticationOptions": {
            "AuthenticationProviderKey": "GatewayAuthenticationScheme",
            "AllowedScopes": ["basket_fullpermission"]
        }
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5014
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/services/discount/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
        "Get",
        "Post",
        "Put",
        "Delete"
      ],
      "UpstreamScheme": "http",
        "AuthenticationOptions": {
            "AuthenticationProviderKey": "GatewayAuthenticationScheme",
            "AllowedScopes": ["discount_fullpermission"]
        }
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5015
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/services/order/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
        "Get",
        "Post",
        "Put",
        "Delete"
      ],
      "UpstreamScheme": "http",
        "AuthenticationOptions": {
            "AuthenticationProviderKey": "GatewayAuthenticationScheme",
            "AllowedScopes": ["order_fullpermission"]
        }
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5016
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/services/payment/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
        "Get",
        "Post",
        "Put",
        "Delete"
      ],
      "UpstreamScheme": "http",
        "AuthenticationOptions": {
            "AuthenticationProviderKey": "GatewayAuthenticationScheme",
            "AllowedScopes": ["payment_fullpermission"]
        }
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:5000"
  }
}
```

I checked the token I sent on jwt.io. The token contains "resource_gateway". I can't understand the problem.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Error 403 usually means the connection completed including the authentication and you did not have permission to access the data on the server.  So the credentials are different from the authentication.  Authentication means you successfully logged-in to the server.  Credentials means your account did not have the permission to read/write the file or access the route.  See authorize attribute at following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api#using-the-authorize-attribute

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the identity server not being up to date. After updating, the problem went away.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).